# How to get the customParameter in Twilio Voice incoming calls

Tags: swift, twilio

How can I get the data from `customParameters` in a Twilio Voice incoming call? I am new to Swift.

```
var callInvite:CallInvite?

// MARK: TVONotificaitonDelegate
    public func callInviteReceived(callInvite: CallInvite) {
        self.sendPhoneCallEvents(description: "LOG|callInviteReceived:", isError: false)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: kCachedBindingDate)
     // How can i use this to get some custom parameter
    // callInvite.customParameters
     var from:String = callInvite.customParameters
     reportIncomingCall(from: from,uuid: callInvite.uuid)
        self.callInvite = callInvite
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`callInvite.customParameters` is a dictionary of the parameters you set in the TwiML. So, if you set a parameter like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>
      <Identity>alice</Identity>
      <Parameter name="test" value="This worked!"/>
    </Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then you should be able to get it in Swift like this:

```swift
public func callInviteReceived(callInvite: CallInvite) {
    // other stuff

    let test: String? = callInvite.customParameters["test"]
}
```

`test` in the above code will be an `Optional`, so you will want to unwrap it to use it.